# Two panes one window in HTML

Tags: html, centering

I am looking to make HTML split the screen vertically using a horizontal rule.

`<hr width="2" size="1080" color="green">`

From there I have two things I don't know how to do and would like to do.

1: have html treat each side as a separate area so that I can center the left side using this css:

`<style type="text/css">`

`html, body, #tbl_wrap { height: 100%; width: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; }`

`#td_wrap { vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; }`
`</style>`

and this html:

```
`<table id="tbl_wrap">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="td_wrap">
<!-- START: Anything between these wrapper comment lines will be centered-->
<div style="border: 1px solid white; display: inline-block;">
</div>
<!-- END: Anything between these wrapper comment lines will be centered -->
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>`
```

2: Have the line I created with the horizontal rule scroll with the page or grow with the length of the page.

Any help or reference material would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style="float:left;border: 0px solid; width: 49%;overflow-y:scroll;text-align: center">
panel 1
</div>
<div style="float: left; height: 100%"><hr width="2" style="height: 100%" color="green"></div>
<div style="float:right; border: 0px solid; width: 49%;overflow-y:scroll;text-align: center">
panel 2
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect!

Comment: is it possible to do this without the scroll bars?

Comment: @Akmedrah - yes remove overflow-y: scroll in both div tags

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful!